# $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ with $\dim null\ T=3$ and $\dim range\ T = 2$

Tags: linear-transformations

Is the following a legitimate example of a linear Transform with $\dim null\ T = 3$ and $\dim range\ T = 2$.

Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbf{R^5}\to\mathbf{R^2}$ defined by the following matrix Equation.
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    c_1\\
    c_2\\
    c_3\\
    c_4\\
    c_5
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  c_4\\
  c_5
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
It is not too difficult to see that $range\ T = \mathbf{R^2}$ consequently $\dim range\ T = 2$ and using the *Rank-nullity-Theorem* it follows that 
$\dim null\ T = \dim \mathbf{R^5} -\dim range\ T= 5-2=3$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, but note you don't need rank-nullity for this! The kernel is clearly $$\ker T = \{(c_{1},c_{2},c_{3},0,0) | c_{1},c_{2},c_{3} \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
which has dimension $3$.